# Rendering two different objects using opengl ES for android

Tags: android, opengl-es

In my program I am rendering a simple triangle and a textured cube, Individually both work fine but when i call the respective draw methods together , the texturing of cube doesn't show.

The onSurfaceCreated function is as shown below:

```
public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig eglConfig) {
        cub.loadGLTexture(gl, this.context);
        //gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);            
        gl.glShadeModel(GL10.GL_SMOOTH);            
        gl.glClearColor(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f);    
        gl.glClearDepthf(1.0f);                    
        gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_DEPTH_TEST);           
        gl.glDepthFunc(GL10.GL_LEQUAL);            
        gl.glHint(GL10.GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL10.GL_NICEST); 
}
```

The onDrawFrame is as shown below:

```
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
    gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);
    gl.glLoadIdentity();
    GLU.gluLookAt(gl, 0, 0, -5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0);
    tri.draw(gl);       
    gl.glRotatef(-90, 1, 0, 0);
    gl.glTranslatef(-6, 0, 0);
    cub.draw(gl); 
}
```

Comment: Why -ve vote for this Question??

Comment: Would someone please answer this question? it is important..

Comment: Where is the source for the `draw` methods of your objects? That's the most important part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer. Actually i just had to clear the color of the 2D model before binding the 3D model to its texture.Thanks everyone.